Oracle OBIEE - Trying to automate deletion of initialization blocks
So I am currently building a PowerShell automation that once a week loads RPD and Catalog files onto one of our servers, then performs additional actions. The automation works in a loop, so whenever an RPD and Catalog file are placed in a specific folder the process initiates.
Most of my automation is complete, but I am struggling to find a reliable way to automate the deletion of initialization blocks (both Repository and Session).
OB Admin Tool Version: 12.2.1.3.0 | Package 171218.1003.000
I tried working with ChatGPT 4.0, and it provided a solution that did not quite work (although it might have worked with some additional effort). The suggested approach was to export the initialization blocks as a list, then run a PowerShell command using the runcat.cmd for each object/block to delete it. In theory, this approach does sound promising but I could not get it to work properly.
Suggestions?

First thing which chatgpt will never tell you is that you're working with an outdated and unsupported version. 12.2.1.3 is out of error correction support since December 2022 already.
Secondly, an initialization block is an RPD object, not a web catalog object and the runcat command line is the web catalog API and hence the wrong tool to use to begin with.
Third, the so-called "additional actions" are supposed to be carried out before you deploy an RPD and/or web catalog. Not after. You put a consistent and coherent package which has been proven to work into a target environment. You don't deploy and then apply changes.
